# Url Amigable Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, url

Me gustaría definir una url personalizada en el `.htaccess`, en **wordpress** viene por defecto así:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On<br>
RewriteBase /sistema/<br>
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]<br>
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f<br>
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d<br>
RewriteRule . /sistema/index.php [L]<br>
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Cuando agrego esto

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ single-perfil.php?amigable=$1
```

> Lo que quiero lograr es que, esa plantilla single-perfil.php reciba la
>   variable (url_amigale).

Debo mencionar que tengo sistema de personas, donde en la tabla persona tengo un campo que dice url_amigale entiendo que esa variable a enviar seria esta amigable=$1

al momento de llamar el archivo single-perfil.php lo hago asi

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esto me funciona sin usar wordpress, pero en wordpress no me funciona y sale pagina no encontrada 404

deseo hacer esto para no estar creando post por cada persona, si no solo usar una plantilla y que el la url amigable salga asi, con la variable que va a recibir en este caso (url_amigable):

**mipagina.com/joseperez**

Gracias

Comment: Saludos Jorge, por curiosidad, ¿Has visto la documentación de Wordpress?

Comment: Si, tienes alguna sugerencia?,

Comment: wordpress toma todo y lo procesa con su index.php, tendrías que armar una página `personas` con su correspondiente `page-personas.php` y acceder por `personas/joseperez`, ó reemplazar la página `404.php` del theme y ver ahí si lo que pidieron y wordpress  no encontró es válido para tu script

Comment: Hola Alo, gracias por tu ayuda, yo ya cree una plantilla single-personas.php pero cuando lo defino en el .htaccess , no me reconoce, como menciono en la pregunta, derrepente tendria que poner la ruta donde esta la plantilla, ya que single-persona.php se encuentra en la carpeta template y no en la raiz principal de wordpress

Answer (score 1):

No es necesario que tú hagas ese archivo, Wordpress lo puede generar automáticamente.

Lo que tienes que hacer es:

```
ajustes>enlaces permanentes>ajustes comunes > [Seleccionar] Nombre de la entrada
```

Da click en guardar cambios

Y listo, tendrás la oportunidad de utilizar URL amigables de una manera muy sencilla ya que la página tomará el nombre de la página según el menú en el que esté.

Comment: Hola Cragser, gracias por tu ayuda pero no es lo que estoy buscando, deseo usar una plantilla por defecto, que reciba una variable y que basada en esa plantilla la url amigable cambien, ejemplo: mipagina.com/juanperez o mipagina.com/rosamorales y asi, pero creo que eso se debe definir en el .htaccess, solo que no se como hacerlo. Gracias